# Does $AA^T$ = I iff A is an orthogonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, transpose, orthogonal-matrices

I know that if $A$ is an orthogonal matrix, then $AA^T = I$.

> However, is it possible to have a non orthogonal square matrix but $AA^T = I$ as well?

A square matrix of size $n$ is orthogonal if the row spaces and column spaces form an orthogonal basis of ${\bf R} ^n$

Comment: What is your definition of orthogonal matrix?

Comment: Usually orthogonal is not $=I$ but $=D$ (diagonal) there is an extra criterion baked in there for $=I$. You would do well to double check the words in your literature.

Comment: @mathreadler: You're confusing terminology. An orthogonal *matrix* has a different definition for an orthogonal *set* of vectors. An orthogonal matrix should properly be called an "orthonormal matrix," as its rows (columns) for an orthonormal set.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I added the definition of an orthogonal matrix in the question.

Comment: @kengchi: Your definition is sloppy. You actually mean the row vectors themselves (or column vectors themselves) form an orthonormal basis. That's precisely what $AA^\top = I$ says if you write down what the matrix product is calculating.

Comment: @TedShifrin so why make the terminology so confusing? That is bad.

Comment: @TedShifrin I would like to know if there exists a matrix which is not an orthogonal matrix, but $AA^T = I $ as well?

Comment: I answered that, @kengchi. The answer is no. $AA^\top=I$ is precisely the statement that the row vectors of $A$ form an orthonormal set. With a linear algebra, you can deduce immediately that $A^\top A=I$ follows, and so the columns form an orthonormal set as well.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, let's get the definitions straight:

- A basis $b_1, \dots, b_n$ of an innerproduct space is called *orthogonal* if each pair $b_i, b_j$ with $i \neq j$ is orthogonal, i.e., if $\langle b_i, b_j \rangle = 0$.
- A basis $b_1, \dots, b_n$ of an innerproduct space is called *orthonormal* if it is orthogonal and every $b_i$ is a unit vector, i.e., if $\langle b_i, b_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$.
- A square matrix $(A_{ij})_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}$ over an innerproduct space is called *orthogonal* if its columns and rows both form orthonormal bases.

Now, if you work out what it means for the columns of $A$ to be orthogonal, then that comes out as $A^T A = I_n$. And, the rows of $A$ are orthogonal if and only if $A A^T = I_n$. Both are equivalent to $A$ is invertible and $A^{-1} = A^T$.

So, if a square matrix satisfies $A A^T = I_n$ (i.e., its rows form an orthonormal basis), then $A^{-1} = A^T$. Therefore, also $A^T A = I_n$ (i.e., its columns form an orthonormal basis) and hence $A$ is an orthogonal matrix.

(Of course, the argument is now hidden in the fact that a left-inverse of a square matrix is automatically a right-inverse and vica-versa. For that, see for instance [If $AB = I$ then $BA = I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i))

Answer (score 1):

The $(i,j)$th element of the product $AA^T$ is just the dot product of the $i$th and $j$th rows of $A$. Thus, the condition $A^TA=I$ means that $A_iA_j=\delta_{ij}$, that is, that the (square of the) norm of each row is $1$ and that the dot product of different rows is $0$, i.e., they are orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

No, the rows (or columns) of $A$ are normalised and orthogonal if and only if $AA^T=I$.

Let the rows of $A$ be $v_i$. Then $a_{ij} = (v_i)_j$, the $j$th component of $v_i$ so
$$ (AA^T)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} a_{jk} = \sum_{k=1}^n (v_{i})_k (v_j)_k = v_i \cdot v_j,  $$
which is $(I)_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$ if and only if the rows of $A$ are normalised and are (pairwise) orthogonal.

The left- and right-inverses of a matrix coincide, so $A^TA=I$ as well, and one can use the same argument to show that the columns of $A$ are orthogonal and normalised.

Answer (score 0):

This question does not mention $A$ is square. Note that without this assumption,  $AA^T=I$ alone does not imply $A$ is orthogonal by OP's definition (as taken precisely).

Answer (score -1):

Hint:
$$
AA^T=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a&c\\b&d\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}a^2+b^2&ac+bd\\ac+bd&c^2+d^2\end{bmatrix}\\
=\begin{bmatrix}v_1\cdot v_1 &v_1\cdot v_2\\v_1\cdot v_2&v_2\cdot v_2\end{bmatrix}
$$
where
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}-&v_1&-\\ -&v_2&-\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: How come $a^2+b^2=v_1\cdot v_1$?