# Why if the columns of a matrix are orthogonal, then $AA^T\neq A^TA=I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Why if the columns of a matrix are orthogonal, then $AA^T\neq A^TA=I$?
I know this isn't true if the columns are *orthonormal*, but since $A^TA=I$, then $A^T=A^{-1}$, and if exists the left inverse, then exists the right inverse such that $AA^{T}=I$. Am I missing something?

Comment: $A$ doesn't have to be square to have orthogonal columns.  So $A^TA = I$ doesn't necessarily imply that $A$ is invertible.

Comment: What if we deal only with square matrices?

Comment: With orthogonal columns, you only have $A^TA$ diagonal, so you don't have $A^TA=I$.

Comment: The problem arises as I saw this in a question: "Now, if you work out what it means for the columns of $$ to be orthogonal, then that comes out as $^=_$. And, the rows of $$ are orthogonal if and only if $^=_$" https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2250266/268627

Comment: @JonathanS. I don't see how that conflicts with anything said in the comment section here. If we deal with square matrices, then $A^TA=I$ and $AA^T=I$ are equivalent, and neither can happen without the other.

Comment: @Arthur I see, my bad. Thanks!